# memomenton scroll in ios broke pure css parallax

Tags: ios, css

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/11ec63xj/1/

Try to open above demo in iphone (ios), the scrolling is not smooth at all. Later I learned to use

```
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
```

but it broke the parallax effect. Any hack to make this smooth?

Comment: I would also like to know the answer to this